# What does "barely" imply when used with a quantity?

Tags: meaning, definition, word-meaning

I was recommended to post this question here, instead of on *English Language & Usage*. In summary, I understand *"barely"* to mean *"equal to, or more than, but not less than"* when used with a quantity, but I think this is inconsistent with the definition *"certainly not more than"* as specified in the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary 7th edition. This is the full definition of *"barely"* from the Dictionary.

[image: Copy of definition of barely]

I believe I understand the first and second definition: *"barely"* implies that something did happen, although it was very close that it didn't. As is also explained here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148031/what-does-barely-imply.

However, I am having trouble understanding the third definition, describing a quantity. Using the first example sentence and substituting in the provided words from the third definition, changes how I understand the  meaning of the sentence.

To me, stating that

> *Just* 50% of the population voted.

is similar to the definition in 1 and 2 and means the population percentage hit 50%, and maybe trickled over a tiny bit, but it is definitely not less than 50% (don't confuse this usage of *just* with how it can be used as a synonym for *only*).

Meanwhile, I interpret

> *Certainly not more than* 50% of the population voted.

as if 50% or less (but probably close to 50%) of the population voted, but definitely not more than 50%.

Combining these two interpretations creates a third definition of  *"barely"*, as a synonym to *"precisely"*, meaning no less *and* no more than 50.000...% of the population voted. I realize this interpretation could also be derived from *"just"* alone. Maybe this could also be related to the root *"bare"*, as it would be a *"naked"* 50%, nothing more and nothing less?

Which, if any, of these interpretations is more accurate to how *"barely"* should be used with a quantity? Does this correct definition reflect the everyday use of *"barely"*, or is it used less strictly to mean *"around"* or *"about"* a quantity?

Comment: A very quick and rough translation for *barely* would be "almost not". *Barely 50%* would be "yeah, we can say it's 50% (or a little above 50), but it almost didn't make it there". (Sorry for posting this as a comment. I haven't read the whole question, though.)

Answer (score 2):

Bare, the root of barely, means "without any(thing) extraneous…." Likewise barely conveys the same meaning: "just that much up to a very little more or less." That is, meeting the lowest requirement for a classification, with a little wiggle room.

The dictionary listed meaning that say the same things.

```
1. Barely audible. Humans hear -8db and the sound was at -7.8db. Just within the range.
2. Barely acknowledged. There was acknowledgement, but nothing extra; no chit-chat.
3. Barely twenty years. Just became 20, or the birthday is within a month. Again, very little else.
4. Barely started to speak when…. I wasn't speaking, then I began and shortly thereafter this event happened.

Barely does not imply preciseness.
```

Answer (score 1):

That third definition (to me) is slightly misleading: "just; certainly not more than a particular amount" doesn't actually state that "a particular amount" is the number quoted:

> The presidential nominee barely got the 50.1% of votes required

...when s/he got 50.2%. Would 51% still qualify for 'barely'? Maybe. 60%? Nope.

Comment: I'd even go further: 'barely' (to me) implies "...and lucky to have done it!" - although that's drawing a bit of a long bow

Answer (score 1):

> Just 50% of the population voted.

It really depends on the context. To me, this implies that exactly 50% (maybe a little rounding, there is often rounding when talking about voting percentages) voted *but you **expected** more people to vote.*  However, I can imagine that to others, or depending on the context, *just* implies that you expected *less* people to vote. In other words, the word *just* does not really imply any sense of "no more than" or "no less than". Instead, it has an implication regarding *expectation* in this example.

---

> Barely 50% of the population voted.

This might actually be a bad example. To me, *barely* does not mean *certainly not more than* in this example. To me, it means that 50% of the people voted, but the percentage exceed 50% by a very small amount. Maybe 50.0001% voted.

But it is possible to imagine something like a news anchor reporting the news. A graphic reads "49.9% go out to vote" while the news anchor say

> Barely 50% of the population voted.

So with rounding, 49.9% can be consider barely 50%.

Here is an example *barely* means *certainly not more than*. A girl is trying on  a tank top, and it is slightly loose around her breasts. She remarks

> I *barely* fill out this top.

In other words, her breast size is *certainly not more than* the breast size of the top.

Answer (score 1):

Barely implies that there is a categorization and that something, while close to the borderline, still fits within this categorization.

```
John barely passed the class.
```

Perhaps John needed a score of at least 70% to pass the class and he got a final score of 72%.

```
Sue barely made it to work on time.
```

Perhaps Sue starts work at 8:30 and arrived at work at 8:29.

```
Barely 50% of the population voted.
```

There is an implication that the categorization is *at least* 50%, which means the actual number could be something like 52%.

Google examples:
[fee.org/articles/barely-half-of-student-loans-are-being-repaid/](http://fee.org/articles/barely-half-of-student-loans-are-being-repaid/)
http://blogs.edweek.org/edweek/high_school_and_beyond/2016/06/only_half_of_colleges_study_ACT_SAT_as_predictors_of_success.html